Why my cmake didnt work as expected with vcpkg
I am trying to use vcpkg with cmake but I got an error(this error is in the problems tab of my vscode project):
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/MyPC/Documents/Opengl/CMakeLists.txt",
    "owner": "cmake-configure-diags",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):By not providing \"Findglfw3.cmake\" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has\nasked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by \"glfw3\", but\nCMake did not find one.\n\nCould not find a package configuration file provided by \"glfw3\" with any of\nthe following names:\n\n  glfw3Config.cmake\n  glfw3-config.cmake\n\nAdd the installation prefix of \"glfw3\" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set\n\"glfw3_DIR\" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If \"glfw3\"\nprovides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been\ninstalled.",
    "source": "CMake (find_package)",
    "startLineNumber": 5,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 5,
    "endColumn": 10000
}]

here is my cpp code:
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
int main(){
    GLFWwindow* window;
    if (!glfwInit()){
        return -1;
    }
    window = glfwCreateWindow(400, 400, "my name", NULL, NULL);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    return 0;
}

here is my cmake code:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30.3)
project(cpp)
add_executable(cpp main.cpp)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(cpp PRIVATE glfw3)

and also the error of main.cpp included no such file or directory.
I expected it to create a window. I tried to reinstall compiler, tried to install visual studio build tools and it can install packages but when I set the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE to what the vcpkg integrate install told me to do, it didn't work.

Please include the exact error message(s) as formatted text in the question.

can you be more specific please? I dont quite understand what you meant.

A suggestion: as you are using MS-Windows and unless you need to use the GCC tool-chain, I would suggest using Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition as is this is much easier to use "out-of-the-box" and in my opinion much more beginner friendly.

You say you have errors but don't include these in the question; so we would have to guess what the errors are.

isnt it the first code block?i copied pasted it from vscode

Variable CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE should contain path, construction -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<value> is for pass value of variable when invoke cmake. If you set the variable in the CMakeLists.txt, then setting should precede project() call, not to be called after it.

Yes set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake") should be set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake") and should be in the CMakeLists.txt before the project(cpp) it doesn't do anything useful after the project()

And don't forget to delete cmake cache after you change toolchain!

ah, 1 more information which is my triplet isx64-mingw-dynamic

and i found out that the error is it didnt find the glfw3-vcpkg.cmake
